# What happens when AMediaCodec_releaseOutputBufferAtTime() [IN DETAIL]

Tags: android-ndk, android-mediacodec, vsync, surfaceflinger

When decoded output buffer is available and you want to render it onto the screen. With MediaCodec NDK APIs, you have an option to call AMediaCodec_releaseOutputBufferAtTime() if you have a native window registered already to render.

My question is what is the code flow once you have called AMediaCodec_releaseOutputBufferAtTime() until the frame gets displayed onto the screen. I know little-little about the flow. Like the function mentioned here calls queueBuffer() with the timestamp and queues the buffer on Native Window. Then this gets acquired on the next VSYNC event, and displayed on the next-next VSYNC event. Is my understanding right?

Also, I want to know what happens once queueBuffer() is called on ANativeWindow until the frame gets displayed onto the screen.